# Problems with Odoo v12 installation

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I need to install Odoo V12 in my laptop and I having some problems with it.
When I run the ./odoo-bin command for running the server this is the log.
[image]

It seems okey but when I run http://localhost:8069/ is not working.

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = odoo
db_password = False
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
addons_path = /opt/odoo/core/addons,/opt/odoo/core/odoo/addons
xmlrpc_port = 8269
```

Postgres user list:
[image]

Anyone knows what's happening?
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Check if db is working and permission on config file.

sudo chown odoo: /etc/odoo-server.conf

sudo chmod 640 /etc/odoo-server.conf

Comment: This ploblem solved, but now it seems problem of the DB. Do you know what's happening? @Plaoo

Comment: Maybe you need to GRANT permission to odoo user, i think

Answer (score 0):

actually problem is with process's pid.

You have to kill process which is running on localhost:8069 port.

fire this commands:-

```
ps aux|grep odoo
```

Their find your command like (ODOO_FOLDER_PATH/odoo-bin )

Kill this process with

```
sudo kill -9 pid(pid is the process id , find where you located the line : second column)
```